# React - shape method

Tags: reactjs

I am going through some React code while I am learning it. I have come across the `shape` method used in `PropTypes`, as I understood we use the `shape` method to validate if the given value is of certain shape, that we pass it as an argument. But, not sure what is it's purpose if we don't pass it any value that we want to validate, like in this example:

```
Field.propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
};
```

Can't we just have it like this:

```
Field.propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

PropTypes is not for production usage it's used in the development environment and it's not the replacement of validation as some newbie people get it wrong.
For example, I had this dropdown component.

```
Dropdown.propTypes = {
  // Notice this I define the shape of object here
  item: PropTypes.shape({
    value: PropTypes.string,
    text: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};
```

Developers who are supposed to use this component they are required to pass item object but the problem is this component will only work when the object has the particular shape like this.

```
{
  value: "value1",
  text: "text1",
 },
```

So, what I did I defined the shape of the object that how item's object should be and if a someone pass wrong shaped object the component will throw the warning in console.

Comment: Yes, and I not wondering about that, I am wondering why is it in this example that I have provided used without parameters, what is it's purpose if we are not checking the shape of the object?

Comment: If you don't pass prop-types it will still be fine and work as expected.

Comment: But, why is it there? If we are not passing any prop-types, what is the point of having it there, that was my question all along.

Comment: When we pass props to our components sometimes it creates confusion that what kind of data this prop will get that's why we pass prop-types in order to prevent confusion that this particular prop will need this type or shape of data.

Comment: Yes, but in my example, we don't define what kind of prop-types data shape we need, so if we haven't defined it, then what is the point of having the method shape?